# render() method is not correctly called after props update

Tags: redux, reactjs

I'm doing a very simple react+redux application where I've a reducer called goals and a container called GoalsContainer.

From App Container I call the action goal for load the initial goals from a local db(indexedDB)

```
dispatch(loadGoals(currentDate));
```

This call the loadGoals from the goals actions:

```
export function loadGoals(currentDate = new Date()){
  return dispatch => {
    var goals = getGoalsFromDB(normalizeDate(currentDate)); // with this I get an array from the db
    dispatch(setLoadGoals(goals));
  }
}

function setLoadGoals(goals) {
  return {
    type: types.LOAD_GOALS,
    goals
  };
}
```

And then in my reducer I've this:

```
export default function goals(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_GOALS:
      return action.goals; // here I set the state of the goal reducer with the array passed via action
    default:
      console.log('Im here');
      return state;
  }
}
```

and this is my GoalsContainer(read the comments in code):

```
class GoalsContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.goals != undefined) {
      console.log('ok called the render'); // in chrome console shows it
      console.log(this.props.goals); // in chrome console shows correctly the goals loaded
      console.log(this.props.goals.length); // it say 2
      if (this.props.goals.length > 0) { // here fails...
        console.log('good');
        console.log(this.props.goals);
        var goalsView = <div>There are goals</div>
      }
      else {
        console.log('why go here?'); // go here
        console.log(this.props.goals);
        var goalsView = <div>No goals</div>
      }
    } else {
      var goalsView = <div>Undefined</div>
    }
    return (
      <div id="goals-main">
        {goalsView}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

GoalsContainer.propTypes = propTypes;

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { goals, environment } = state;
  const { currentDate } = environment;

  return {
    goals,
    currentDate
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GoalsContainer);
```

The problem is that when it does the if check, it fails(like if there are 0 goals), but in chrome console show correctly the goals array...
Then if I force with some workaround the render(), all works correctly.

What I've done wrong ?

Comment: Should your LOAD_GOALS reducer return your new state?

Comment: What is the source for the `getGoalsFromDB` function?

Comment: Can you show where exactly you call the dispatch function?

Comment: @idbehold here the database.js https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78371ec70a408fc6e7b94ef158d71e63

Comment: @yjcxy12 not sure what you mean, but I call loadGoals action from another action of another reducer...look here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78371ec70a408fc6e7b94ef158d71e63

Comment: The situation sounds very odd that on first line `this.props.goals.length` evaluates to 2 and `this.props.goals.length > 0` is false. I would recommend adding `debugger;` statement right before `if (this.props.goals.length > 0)`, and check in the chrome dev tool what is the value of `this.props.goals.length > 0`, then step though to see if it goes inside the condition.

Comment: Your reducers need to be pure functions. If you're calling `loadGoals` from inside a reducer, that's likely your problem. See https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-pure-and-impure-functions

Comment: @JosiahSprague so how could fix it ? I mean, I want loadGoals during the initialization (so initEnvironement action)...what you suggest ?

Comment: You need to call `loadGoals` from the action creators (before or after a `dispatch()` call, rather than from inside a reducer.

Comment: @JosiahSprague sorry I don't understand yet :( this is my code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a7debcb4a3224802e017e65230c7b05 (this is from the action...)
should I move dispatch(loadGoals(currentDate)); out of dispatch or you mean something like this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/014e30bdb96b1cc76a86e0c8e0490443 ?

Comment: Had trouble posting a code sample here, so I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you use https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk or not. To use reducer returning function you should definitely install it.

Comment: I already use it...in my configureStore I've also: applyMiddleware(thunk, router, logger)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow all of the parts of your code from random gists. What happens if you change your `GoalsContainer` to be;

```
class GoalsContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.goals);
    return (
      <div id="goals-main">
        {(this.props.goals.length >= 1)?<div>There are goals</div>:<div>Nope!</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What gets logged to the console?

Comment: In console.log it show correctly the array with the object...but in the render it shows Nope!

Comment: Hmm, how many times is the console.log called? Doing `console.log('goals"', this.props.goals);` might make that easier to see.

Comment: Maybe your goals aren't actually an array, and don't have a length property. Try logging `this.props.goals.length` too. If it's logging correctly when the render method is called, then it should be returning the correct markup. The only thing I can suggest is to keep trying smaller and smaller bits until you narrow down the problem. Reduce the problem and you'll eventually find it.